# Android Studio Debugger weird behavior

Tags: android-studio, debugging, gradle, android-ndk

I have an Android app which has a significant amount of native C++ code in it. 
When debugging the C++ code, sometimes the debugger does not stop on breakpoints, or stops on the wrong line, or it might skip a few lines when single stepping through the code.
The C++ code is built with compilation optimization set to `-o0`, `minifyEnabled` is set to false in Gradle.

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4 and running on Mac OSX 10.12.6

Anyone encountered similar behavior and can shed some light?